# java.net.socketException The Operation timed out

Tags: android

Im trying to send the data from my HTC Desire to a tomcat server which
is installed in my PC through Wi-Fi from my android application..

I can able to send the data from the Emulator. but i can't able to
send the data from the Mobile.

Im getting an exception  when i sent data from the mobile..The
exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: The operation timed
out..

I have included all the permissions in the android manifest file like
INTERNET, ACCESS_WIFI..

I saw some of the blogs related to this Exception.. I've tried all the
ways that they have suggested..

But no use... Is it related to any firewall protection??

Thanks in advance
Uday Kiran Pichika

Comment: Post your code please